# Time-out error uploading file using Dropbox API

Tags: php, file, upload, timeout, dropbox

I try to upload a file to DropBox using their API and PHP.
Thats the code:

```
require_once "dropbox/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;
    $appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app_info.json");

$csrfTokenStore = new dbx\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuth($appInfo, "NoteBoxApp/0.01", "http://localhost/notes", $csrfTokenStore, null);


$title=$_POST["titulo"].".txt";
$nota=$_POST["conteudo"];

$accessToken=$_SESSION["token"];
$clientIdentifier=$_SESSION["userId"];
$client= new dbx\Client($accessToken, $clientIdentifier);

$file = fopen($title, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($file, $nota);
$stat = fstat($file);
$size = (int) $stat['size'];

$dropboxPath="/Aplicativos/Notes01";
try{
    $metadata = $client->uploadFile($dropboxPath, dbx\WriteMode::add(), $file, $size);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Exceção: ",  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
fclose($file);
```

I always get the exception

> Error executing HTTP request: Operation too slow. Less than 1024
>   bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds

I cant see why! I using XAMPP on localhost!...
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I can't  upload a file open in "write" mode!

I have to close the file first then open it again in "read" mode and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file you are trying to upload is not empty? It seems that you aren't sending any data at all.